# Derefference Date

Tags: arrays, perl, datetime

I have a little script where I want to return an array of Dates between two dates.

Problem is that the scalar that is being added is by reference, how do I store a copy or the derefferenced value

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $now        = DateTime->today;
my $start_date = DateTime->today;
$start_date = $start_date->subtract( days => 45 );

my @dates;
while ( $start_date <= $now ) {
    push @dates, $start_date;
    $start_date->add( days => 1 );
}

my $date;
foreach (@dates) {
    print $_->ymd('/'), "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you want the today's date where you are located instead of the one at UTC+0000: `DateTime->now(time_zone=>'local')->set_time_zone('floating')->truncate(to=>'day')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *clone* the object as you push it onto the array, like this

```
my @dates;

while ( $start_date <= $now) {
   push @dates, $start_date->clone;
   $start_date->add( days => 1 );
}

foreach (@dates) {
  print $_->ymd('/'), "\n";
}
```

but that is wasteful if you want only ever want the YMD string from each date. You can just push that instead

```
my @dates;

while ( $start_date <= $now) {
   push @dates, $start_date->ymd('/');
   $start_date->add( days => 1 );
}

print "$_\n" for @dates;
```

You can set up the array more simply by working on the elements of the array itself, as follows

```
my @dates = (DateTime->today);
unshift @dates, $dates[0]->clone->subtract(days => 1) for 1 .. 45;
```

But in the end it is neater, and probably faster, to use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) to do the same thing. It is a core module, and so shouldn't need installing if your copy of perl is at all recent, it is far smaller than [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime), and is probably faster

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';


my @dates = map { localtime() - $_ * ONE_DAY } reverse 0 .. 45;

print $_->ymd('/'), "\n" for @dates;
```

**output**

```
2014/07/24
2014/07/25
2014/07/26
2014/07/27
2014/07/28
2014/07/29
2014/07/30
2014/07/31
2014/08/01
2014/08/02
2014/08/03
2014/08/04
2014/08/05
2014/08/06
2014/08/07
2014/08/08
2014/08/09
2014/08/10
2014/08/11
2014/08/12
2014/08/13
2014/08/14
2014/08/15
2014/08/16
2014/08/17
2014/08/18
2014/08/19
2014/08/20
2014/08/21
2014/08/22
2014/08/23
2014/08/24
2014/08/25
2014/08/26
2014/08/27
2014/08/28
2014/08/29
2014/08/30
2014/08/31
2014/09/01
2014/09/02
2014/09/03
2014/09/04
2014/09/05
2014/09/06
2014/09/07
```

---

**Update**

To store strings in the array instead of `Time::Piece` objects, you could write this instead

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my $today = localtime;
my @dates = map { ($today - $_ * ONE_DAY)->ymd('/') } reverse 0 .. 45;

print "$_\n" for @dates;
```

The output is identical to that of the previous program.

Comment: With your neater version how do I map the string version of the date, I only need the ymd

Comment: @PrivatMamtora: I've added to my answer to show you.

Answer (score 2):

apparently there is a function for it called clone()

so this

```
push(@dates, $start_date);
```

changes into

```
push(@dates, $start_date->clone);
```